# Why are values of regular rational maps well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field.

> **Definition** A rational map $$\phi = [f_0,\dots,f_n]: V_1 \to V_2$$ (where $V_1, V_2 \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ are projective varieties) is called **regular** at $P \in V_1$ if there is a function $g \in K(V_1)$ such that
>
> 1. each $gf_i$ is regular at P, and
> 2. $(gf_i)(P) \neq 0$ for some $i$.

In Silverman's book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, we set $$
\phi(P) = [(gf_0)(P),\dots,(gf_n)(P)]
$$
in this case.

> **Question** Why is this definition well-defined? In particular, why does another element $h \in K(V_1)$ satisfying 1. and 2. give the same value?

**Approach**

- I tried to rewrite $$gf_i = \frac{p_i}{q_i}$$ and $$hf_i = \frac{r_i}{s_i}$$ where $p_i,q_i,r_i,s_i \in K[V_1]$ such that $q_i(P) \neq 0$ and $s_i(P) \neq 0$ since 1. must be satisfied. I wanted to show that if $(gf_i)(P) \neq 0$, then $h f_i (P) \neq 0$ as well because this is want we want to achieve for well-definedness. But my comptations lead to nothing.

Could you please help me explain this definition? Thank you!

Comment: What is his definition of $K(V_1)$ and of $gf_i (P)$?

Comment: $K(V_1)$ is the function field of $V_1$ and $(g f_i) (P)$ the evaluation of $g f_i$ at $P$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the evaluation is $g(P)f_i(P)$?

Comment: @Yuongsu: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then for two such functions $g,h$ the ratio of $gf_i(P)/hf_i(P)$ will be the same (for any i), so they define the same point.

Comment: But here you are assuming that $g f_i$ and $h f_i$ are both not $0$ in $P$ for every index $i$. But condition 2. says that there exists only at least one index with that condition, so I am not convinced yet that your argument is valid. Furthermore, we have to scale with the same scalar, so the point is the same, not with different scalars.

Comment: If $g(P)$ or $h(P)$ is zero, then this already violates condition 2. (But can $g(P)$ be zero?) Maybe, I should've said that you only consider the ratio where $f_i(P) \neq 0$.